# UDP Transport Hints in ROSJava

Tags: android-core, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to find out if there are any UDP capabilities in ROSJava as of this moment.  An earlier question back in February had asked the same question (I apologize for duplicating), however, I am trying to see if there is any new/recent news on the subject.  I looked through the code and saw nothing, so the answer seems like no.  Just want to make sure I didn't miss something.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44348/udp-transport-hints-in-rosjava/) by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 213 on 2012-09-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You didn't miss anything. There is no UDP support. Please file an issue and star it. You'll be notified if there are changes to it:

http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/list

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1